# How to properly clear, add or edit data in JTable? And how to control TableModelListener?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

I have a big problem with `JTable`. Here is how it works:

- a user adds a new `Shape` to `Model`
- `Controller` updates `Model` and sends a notification to `View` to update
- `View` gets data from `Model` and renders them

I use `addRow(...)` method to add rows of shapes. But it adds the whole `List` of shapes to the curent data (so I get this: shape1, shape1, shape2, shape1, shape2, shape3 for three shapes). I tried to delete rows somehow or `setRowCount(0)` but none of it worked correctly.

`TableModel`

```
package dpo.mvc.view.table;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import dpo.mvc.model.Shape;
import dpo.mvc.view.View;
import dpo.mvc.view.ViewListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel implements ViewListener {

    private View view;

    public CustomTableModel(View view, String ... columns) {
        this.view = view;
        this.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        this.addTableModelListener(new TableListener(view));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return column != 0;
    }

    private void load() {
        for (Shape shape : view.getModel().getShapesList()) {
            this.addRow(new Object[] {shape.getId(), shape.getPositionX(), shape.getPositionY(), shape.getSize()});
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        load();     
    }

}
```

`TableListener`

```
package dpo.mvc.view.table;

import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;

import dpo.mvc.view.View;

public class TableListener implements TableModelListener {

    private View view;

    public TableListener(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        int changedRow = e.getFirstRow();
        String[] shapeData = getData();

        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
            view.getController().shapeChanged(shapeData);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: sort of off topic but using AbstractTableModel in my mind is almost always much simpler, and much clearer than using DefaultTableModel. Doing so, allows you to keep the data in the form that makes sense to you, rather than converting them to object arrays which is just ridiculous. (The only thing that you are responsible for by doing this is firing the appropriate table events when data changes).

Comment: Every time you render you want to add more rows?

Comment: Shouldn't the _model_ notify the _view_, rather than having the _controller_ do it? Do the `Shape`s appear in the `JTable` or elsewhere?

Comment: please reads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event, with another linked thread too

Comment: @trashgod in mvc, model should always notify the view and with controller  doing this it is a bad design? I found many articles about mvc and everyone says it differently

Comment: whatever a particular theory says to do or not to do - it's useless if the framework has its own ideas ;-) In Swing, the model notifies whoever is interested. Who exactly that is (might be the view itself or its ui delegate), is unspecified and varies across component types. You dont really need to know (nor want you to know :-) - simply implement the model to comply to its contract, everthing else will happen auto-magically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Shape` is meant to appear in another component, register the class containing that component as a `TableModelListener` using the [`addTableModelListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#addTableModelListener%28javax.swing.event.TableModelListener%29) method of your `TableModel`. If the `Shape` is meant to appear in the `JTable`, you'll probably want to implement `TableCellRenderer`, as discussed in [*How to Use Tables: Using Custom Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) and shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2834484/230513).