# TableModelListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, tablecelleditor

I am making a student record application... I want a column in it which is editable.
I have attached table model listener on table and on that column i m saving all the updating values

```
if(table.getSelectedColumn() == 3 && table.getSelectedRow() != -1 && tme.getType() ==     TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
{
// my code here
table.cellEditAt(row,column); // this is giving me error
}
```

`table.cellEditAt` automatically calls table model event and that is producing a infinite loop... Any other method to automatically select a cell for editing????

Comment: crossposted http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/405375

Comment: Sorry didnt understand you... Let me stat my problem again, I making an app which saves data from jtable to database on entering in the cell. I want to attach a listener to the cell. So after searching alot i found tablemodellistener. In table model listener , there is a method table changed. I Every thing works fine in table changes except this code                                                                table.editCellAt(row,col); // This code creates an infinite loop. I cant paste my full code because its interlinked with 4 classes and contain some private information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to post an SSCCE. We are not mind readers. We can't guess what your editCellAt(...) method does. If it causes a loop, then that would be because you are somehow changing the model and generating another TableModelEvent. Don't do this!

If the problem is somehow related to placing a cell in edit mode, then I would guess you need to wrap that code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to make sure the processing of the original event is completed before you place another cell in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstate your issues, for example based on my question about [Infinite loop by implements TabelModelListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event) linked to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082801/java-tablemodellistener-and-live-feed-listener/8085360#8085360),

Comment: Sorry didnt understand you... Let me stat my problem again, I making an app which saves data from jtable to database on entering in the cell. I want to attach a listener to the cell. So after searching alot i found tablemodellistener. In table model listener , there is a method table changed. I Every thing works fine in table changes except this code                                                                table.editCellAt(row,col);