# How to know that cell data has not been changed or modified?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I am designing a Table that allows users **IN PLACE CELL EDITING** i.e. user can edit table Cell in place. I would like to mark the row as "Edit" by setting the image of "EDIT" to the first cell of the row, if any cell of that row has been updated or edited. I have added a `CellEditorListener` to the `JTable` but how would I know that cell data has not been changed or modified ? As user done with editing program control takes me to the editingStopped() but how I come to know that user has not updated any data?

```
CellEditorListener cellEditorListener = new CellEditorListener() {

 public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
  //If cell has been edited
 }

public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
 // If cell has not been updated                        
}
};
```

I am assuming that I will get my program control to editingCanceled() when user has been return without updating data from the cell. Is there any other approach ?

Answer (score 2):

- you have look at [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html), that can help you with fired events,
- please carrefully read [this question and with answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event)
- [TableCellListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) by @camickr has access to the old value

Answer (score 0):

You should save the base state of your JTable (clone the model?) before you start making changes. That way, whenever a cell changes, you can compare it to the original value to see whether its changed or not

Comment: A `PropertyChangeEvent` can be used in this context, as shown in the link(s) provided by @mKorbel.