# Jtable cell value changed on ke pressed event in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, onkeypress

As I am a beginer in Java Programming Language, I am making an ERP,
I am working with jTable,
I have three columns (item quantity, rate, amount)
in the manner that i am writing item quantity in a column and then on typing its rate i want change the value of amount column.
I need your help.
Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: You have told us your goal, but you haven't told us what you've tried or where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- see my question about [Why never change the notifier in receiving a change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event)
- override `setValueAt()` for columns `quantity` and `rate` instead of using `TableModelListener`,
- updates fired from `TableModelListener` could be / may be fragile, breakable, then with bunch of exceptions caused stops of updates in JTable cells

Comment: Override isCellEditable to change the editable state of the cell...

Comment: Thanx for your answer, I have already found a solution and it is much similar as yours.