# JTableModelListener.tableChanged() thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Is the `tableChanged()` call on a `JTable` thread safe, so that i am allowed to call it from another Thread, which for example finished downloading something? I imagine `tableChanged()` to just put a new Event into the Event queue, so that the Event-Dispatcher-Thread will update the `JTable` at some point in the future, but is this adding thread safe?

Comment: [tableChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#tableChanged(javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent) is event from [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html), then this event can be genereted from XxxTableModel,     don98t to use this event as intializator for your code, to use, override setValueAt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer no, it is not thread safe and all calls to `tableChanged` should be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

If you need to update a `TableModel`, either disconnect it from the table and apply it in a single step (`setModel`) within the confines of the EDT or sync the updates to the model back to the EDT through the use of a `SwingWorker` or `EventQueue.invokeLater`

General rule of thumb with Swing, assume nothing is thread safe and guard for it.

> I imagine tableChanged() to just put a new Event into the Event queue, so that the Event-Dispatcher-Thread will update the JTable at some point in the future, but is this adding thread safe?

Not all events get scheduled on the Event Queue, many are simply processed by a `for-next` loop within the component, looping through the registered listeners directly, as is the case for `TableModel`'s `fire` event methods...

For example, from the `AbstractTableModel`...

```
public void fireTableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
    Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
    // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
    // those that are interested in this event
    for (int i = listeners.length-2; i>=0; i-=2) {
        if (listeners[i]==TableModelListener.class) {
            ((TableModelListener)listeners[i+1]).tableChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This means that the `fireTableChanged` method will be executed within the context of the thread that called it, and will notifiy its listeners from within the same thread.

This means that if you were to call `TableModel.setValueAt` from a different thread, it would call `fireTableCellUpdated`, which would call `fireTableChanged` and would eventually call `tableChanged` within the context of that thread...

As a side note, you should not be calling `JTable#tableChanged` directly, it's public as a side effect (inner classes weren't around when `JTable` was created ;)), you should be making modifications to the table's model and allowing the model to trigger the event notifications.

**Updated...**

Consider this very basic test...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"One"}, 1);
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                System.out.println("isEventDispatchingThread - " + EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
            }
        });

        model.setValueAt("Test", 0, 0);

    }

}
```

Which will output...

```
 isEventDispatchingThread - false
```

Because the update did not occur within the EDT, in fact, it was not dispatched by the Event Queue at all...

**Updated with instantiation of EDT and separate update thread**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JLabel("Boo"));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"One"}, 1);
                model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("isEventDispatchingThread - " + EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
                    }
                });

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        model.setValueAt("Test", 0, 0);
                    }
                });
                t.start();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Outputs...

```
 isEventDispatchingThread - false
```

Comment: you cant't fire this event programatically(change in XxxTableModel), but answer is - yes is thread safe, because all Listeners in Swing are done on EDT

Comment: @mKorbel No there not, many are called from the context from which they were originally called.  If the changed (to the table model for instance) occured within the EDT, the `TableListener#tableChanged` would be notified within the same thread context.  Conversly, if it's changed on a different thread, then `tableChanged` would still be called within the same thread context (not the EDT)...and yes, I've done this and it bites...hard - therefore the answer is NO, it's not thread safe...

Comment: after edit is better answer +1 but don't to mix updates out of EDT to model and refresh JTables view from TableModelListener (seems like as this is OPs issue)

Comment: @mKorbel Yeah, think I mentioned that in the second paragrah as well as mentioned not updating the table directly (by calling `tableChanged`) in the updates somewhere...

Comment: @sh4kesbeer updates to XxxTableModel should be wrapped into invokeLater, then event from TableModelListener is just for debugging, if ordering of events is correctly coded, again don't to use TableModelListener as notifier for JTables view, [those reasons, rest is described very well here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event)

Comment: my comment to `public class Test {` ---> EDT (as thread catchable by `isEventDispatchThread`) required to use `invokeLater`, creating `Top-Level Containaer`, I'm think that programatically showing any `JComponent` (e.g.`JTextField.setVisible(treu);`) too, otherwise there isn't any EDT at all :-), really

Comment: @mKorbel Updated, still prints `false`

Comment: helped me a lot in understanding how it works, thanks!