# How to add a table listener to a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

I am having problems with fixing something in my program.  Basically I know how to use action Listeners but there is no option to add one to a `JTable`. How is this done?

Basically I want to add an action Listener to my table so that every time a value is changed it will update that field in my data base.

I.E.

```
JTable.addActionListener (new ActionListener) {
    // text is changed
    updateDataBase();
};
```

Comment: override setValueAt, there no reason to use TableModelListener for basics task (Basically I know how to use action Listeners but there is no option to add one to a JTable.), TableModelListener isn't designated to notify about changes from JTable to the rest of Swing GUI

Comment: @Seamus please learn to [Accept Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) on this site.

Comment: @Sharp edge :-) I'm doubt it in,[because no one of the answer in this thread is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add a listener to the [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html):

```
yourtableObject.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

  public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
     // your code goes here, whatever you want to do when something changes in the table
  }
});
```

[`TableModelEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html) contains row and column number and type of modification.

> `TableModelEvent` is used to notify listeners that a table model has changed.

Comment: public class tableListener implements TableModelListener  {


      public tableListener(){


        JTableSchedule.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){

       @Override 
       public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
          
            System.out.println("DataChanged");
           Methods method = new Methods();
            try {
                method.updateDb();
                              
                  
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SchedulerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

Comment: Sharp edge I done what you said but it won't work. It says it's not abstract. Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @SeamusOConnor why are you making a separate class for this ? Just use the above snippet in your class where you have used `JTable`, and rite after initializing `JTable`

Comment: @SharpEdge I am using the same technique, actually I am executing this line "noOfItemsTextField.setText(""+saleTable.getRowCount());", so whenvever the property of table changes this line will execute and it will count the total number of items in the table and will set the result on a textfield as defined in the code, but the problem is that whenever table data changes for the very first time then this code does not show the rowcount value, but when second time executed then it shows all the rowcount. Please tell me why this does not work on the first call but work on other calls

Comment: @TaimoorKhan could you show your code ? Or post a separate question and share me the link.

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

What you will want to do is register a `TableModelListener` with the `JTable`'s model and monitor for changes there

You may also find [How to Write a Table Model Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html) of some use

The kind of thing you are look for is

- `TableModel#getType` equals `TableModelEvent.UPDATE`
- `TableModel#getFirstRow` and `TableModel#getLastRow` are typically equals (singularly that a single row was update), this may or may not be relevant, that's up to you to decide
- `TableModel#getColumn` is not equal to `TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS`, this signifies that a single cell was updated.  Again, this may or may not be important, but if the cell was edited by the user, this will be set

Take a look at [`javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an event when there is a change in selection you can use:

```
table.getSelectionModel()addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent l) {
    //action
    }
});
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/TableSelectionEventsandListeners.htm

Comment: It's near to the question, but it not really answer to this question. It ask for listener of table add event. the accepted answer seems perfect, and your answer seems to correspond to another event. So I think it's not a really good idea to update a 6yo post for it

Comment: the reason I found this question was because of me looking for the usual event for Actions, in this case the selected answer only works when editing a cell, but my answer is for when you change rows, be it by using keyboard or the mouse, i think it may be useful depending on de expected behaivoir