# TableModelListener between two different JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

I am currently working with two JTable. Each of them has its own custom TableModel.

In the first JTable i have items that can  be select (checkbox). The second one starts empty.  When i check a line in the first table, the backgroundColor of the line changes (thanks to a preparedRenderer method) and i would like the content of the checked line to be added in the second JTable.

I suppose i should use a TableModelListener but i don't see how i tell the second Table (and its model) to listen to the first one.

Does anyone have some thought about that ?

Here is a sample of what the code i got look like :

```
public class MyClass {

    private Model1 model1;
    private Model2 model2;

    private JTable table1;
    private JTable table2;

    public void myMethod()
    {
        table1 = new JTable();
        model1 = new Model1();
        table1.setModel(model1);

        table1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) 
            {
                //Here some code to enable a button when at least one row is checked
                //that works fine
            }
        });


        table2 = new JTable();
        model2 = new Model2();
        table2.setModel(model2);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Probably better to use a `TableModelListener` on the first table's model to detect changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update model2 in the listener of model1 and refresh its table2:

```
public class MyClass  {

    private Model1 model1;
    private Model2 model2;

    private JTable table1;
    private JTable table2;

    public void myMethod()
    {
        table1 = new JTable();
        model1 = new Model1();
        table1.setModel(model1);

        table2 = new JTable();
        model2 = new Model2();
        table2.setModel(model2);

        table1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) 
            {
                //Here some code to enable a button when at least one row is checked
                //that works fine
                Object aValue = "something"; //fill
                int row = 1; //fill
                int column = 1; //fill
                model2.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
                model2.fireTableDataChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. never to use fireTableDataChanged() out of models definition (class, void), 2.  fireTableDataChanged() reseting all custom setting, properties for JTable, its model

Comment: 1. fireTableDataChanged() is a public method. I cannot see such a restriction  in javadoc you have mentioned. Please explain what you think of.

Comment: 2. The questioner wants to add "content of the checked line" to the 2nd table. I do not exactly know what that means. It can be a cell level update or row level update-insert-delete or a total table update. There are more sophisticated methods for those cases: fireTableRowsInserted, fireTableRowsUpdated, fireTableRowsDeleted, fireTableCellUpdated. I have written fireTableDataChanged in this template code because I do not know this. By javadoc fireTableDataChanged will "redraw the table from scratch" which might be unnecessary in case of partial change.

Comment: Well in my first table a row is basically  "checkbox | name | title" where name and title are String. In the second table i just want to insert the name and title from the first table.

Comment: The TableModel, not the application code is responsible for notifying the table when data in the model changes. So only the TableModel should invoke a fireXXX(...) method.

Answer (score 2):

> working with two JTable. Each of them has its own custom TableModel.
>
> In the first JTable i have items that can be select (checkbox). The
>   second one starts empty. When i check a line in the first table, the
>   backgroundColor of the line changes (thanks to a preparedRenderer
>   method)

- don't to use `TableModelListener`, override `setValueAt` (`Each of them has its own custom TableModel.`) for first `XxxTableModel` e.g. `tableModelFirts.setValueAt(whatever_linked_in_second_model)`
- `TableModelListener` could not be used [as notifier to change value in model, inside or outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys !

I finally managed to get it working. I used a mix of your solutions.

In my tableListener (from table1) i get the checked object and call the setValue method from my table2 that i have override to do what i want (because my object is a custom object).

Comment: Then you should "accept" Laszlo's answer instead since his suggestion was to use a TableModelListener. By "accepting" the answer people will know the problem has been solved.